# How can I upgrade a Windows Store App-project from .NET 4.5 to .NET 4.5.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, azure-devops

I have Windows Store App project (XAML), targeted for .NET Framework 4.5. Now I'm referencing a library (Prism) and upon building it on Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online/Team Foundation Service, TFS Build) I get the following warning:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (1605): The primary reference "Microsoft.Practices.Prism.StoreApps"
>   could not be resolved because it was built against the
>   ".NETCore,Version=v4.5.1" framework. This is a higher version than the
>   currently targeted framework ".NETCore,Version=v4.5".

My question: **how can I upgrade my project to target version 4.5.1 of .NETCore?**

I can choose the version when creating a new project, but cannot find where to do it for my existing project. It used to be in the properties window (Application tab) for the project, but not for Win Store Apps it seems.

Comment: You can't target a specific .NET Framework version in a Store app, you target a Platform version.  You need 8.1 and have the VS2013 build tools installed on the machine.

Comment: It's not sufficient to have the Microsoft Build Tools 2013 package installed. I'm having the same problem and it's not working. From all the other literature I've read online, it looks like a Visual Studio 2013 installation is required to develop for .NETCore v4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

To build Windows Store apps for 8.1 (.NETCore v4.5.1), you have to select the correct template for Visual Studio 2013: `TfvcTemplate.12.xaml` instead of the default template.
(see point 8 on https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/build-your-apps-vs)

[image]